# OAuth sign in for regular and mobile site get different provideruserid

Tags: .net, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4

My website lets users register with a username & password or using their facebook, twitter, microsoft or google account using OAuth. Now i'm building a mobile site and i want to offer the same way of registering / signing in.

The issue i'm having is that OAuth returns different ids for the same users depening on the url that requests the authentication. Since my mobile site is on a different sub domain the returned id is different and therefore doesn't detect if the user has already registered on the regular website.

Is there a common approach to deal with this situation?

Comment: It's actually returning a different Id (ProviderUserId) based on the hostname of the website.  Did you ever come up with a workaround or fix?

Comment: I haven't done any work on it for a while. But i'm thinking in making a websservice on the www domain the mobile site can connect to to authenticate. But again, i haven't really thought about it much yet. When i found a solution i will post it here.

Comment: I did a "dirty workaround" as this just happes for Google at my site: If no user matches I check for another user with the same e-mail address which is already linked to Google and then add the second provider id tho that user. ATTENTION: This should only be used when you verify the e-mail addresses of you users.